# How to prove that $f=id_A$?

Tags: functions

We have a surjective function $f:A\rightarrow A$ and we know that $f\circ f=f$.

How do I prove that $f=id_A$?

Answer (score 6):

Let $x \in A$. Then since $f$ is surjective, there exists a $y \in A$ such that $$f(y)=x$$

This implies $$f(f(y))= f(y)$$

$$f(x)=x$$

Since our choice of $x$ was arbitrary, we're done.

Comment: I don't underrstand your final step

Comment: It uses what he wrote down was a result of $f$ being both a self-map and surjective.

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee could you explain your funal step a bit more?

Comment: @arturodonjuan but he cant use the fact that f i a selfmap, since thats what we need to prove

Comment: @bolzanoman There are so few steps that it is hard to see what is meant with final step.- Given $x\in A$, we want to show that $f(x)=x$. By surjectivity of $f$, there exists $y$ with $x=f(y)$. Then by this and the property of $f$, we have $f(x)=f(f(y))=(f\circ f)(y)=f(y)=x$ as desired.

Comment: @bolzanoman he substituted in the first line, $f(y)=x$.

Comment: @everybody I'm stupid! Only now understand Thanks a bunch!